# Have any sci-novels been written based on the ideas of Marshall T Savage?

Tags: inspiration, the-millennial-project

Have any sci-novels been written based on the ideas of Marshall T Savage, as detailed in his book "[The Millennial Project](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0316771635)"?

Comment: i've never read the book (though it looks very interesting), however, based on the editorial review it appears that the book itself covers a broad range of topics from oceanic cities, intra-stellar colonization and exploitation out to inter-stellar colonization. many books and series deal with one or more of these aspects and ideas. is there something in particular you are looking for, or having not read the book is there something i am missing?

Comment: I mean the specific implementations he talks about; his "universe" if you like. I felt that anyone who could give the answer would know what the question was, but maybe I need to add more detail, unfortunately that will have to wait until later today :o)

Answer (score 1):

I find that the scifi novel series "[Manifold: Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold%3a_Time)" by Stephen Baxter has some attributes of the "The Millennial Project" (WARNING SPOILERS).

"The Millennial Project" has 8 steps. And here is where "Manifold:Time" displays similarities and disimilarities:

1. Foundation: A private firm is created for the purpose.
2. Aquarius: Genetically-engineered cuttlefish are trained in an under-ocean lab to mine asteroids. (Maybe they could have sent monkeys but cuttlefish are easily adaptable to zero-gravity of asteroids).
3. Bifrost: Instead of free-electron lasers, conventional (but modified) boosters are used.
4. Asgard: Not mentioned.
5. Elysium: Not mentioned.
6. Solaria: Cuttlefish mine asteroids.
7. Galactia: Mentioned briefly.